# Jquery submit single form field using setInterval?

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, submit

I was looking over [this jquery timer](http://jsfiddle.net/GNrUM/2/) on jsfiddle and it works pretty well. However I want to submit a single form field every x amount of seconds. So for an HTML form like:

```
<form id="form">
    <input id="first_name" />
    <input type="hidden" id="referrer" />
</form>
```

I would like to submit *only* the #referrer field to a specific URL without refreshing, redirecting, etc. Possbile? The back end where this is located is not performing any redirects or anything, I just need to get that field value to the backend every so often.

Would I be needing `$(#form).submit(){ //do something}` since I'm not actually submitting a form? Just sending a variable to another URL.

Ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery has [a nice load of Ajax methods](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/).

You seem to be using the GET method, because that is the default for `form` (`<form method="get">`), so the [`$.get()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) function seems fine for you. Something along the lines of:

```
var value = $('#referrer').val(); //let's say the value is the_value
$.get('specific_url', { referrer: value });
```

This will send a GET request to `specific_url` with the query string set to `referrer=the_value`. Please read the linked documentation on how to use this method.